# Does setting HttpCacheability.Public also cache the page on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have these lines in my global.asax (basically because of [Can I add my caching lines to global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469348/can-i-add-my-caching-lines-to-global-asax))

The thing I want to now understand is whether this code purely adds the HTTP headers to the page or does it also make .Net cache this page on the server for 300 seconds?

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page will be stored in output cache, too. Are you sure you want to do this for every page on the site?

[KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811431)