# Enable Cache Globally from Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, iis-7.5

I am trying to enable server-side cache (Output Caching) globally from Global.asax in a MVC3 project.

I tried this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Contains("private"))
        {
            return;
        }
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
        Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Host"] = true;
        Response.Cache.VaryByParams["myparam"] = true;
    }
```

But if I put a `DateTime.Now` in one of my pages it changes on every request. So it doesn't seems to work.

I have also tried to put it on `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` event as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469348/can-i-add-my-caching-lines-to-global-asax) with no luck.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior from Global.asax?

Note: I want to filter some URL's from being cached.

### Edit: Started a bounty

Steven V's answer put me on the right track, but after hours of developing "my own cache system" extending `ActionFilterAttribute`, I had a lot of problems with threads, response types and cache was mashing results so it's a complete disaster (I think it's not even worth pasting the code here).

Another option is to control it directly from IIS, if there is a cache module for IIS that can help me achieve this or some configuration than can be made on IIS's Output Caching that would be also very helpful. In the end what I try to achieve is fully URL related.

The main idea is to have a global cache enabled with filtering, URL depending, controlled from a centralized area.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve the output caching by adding `OutputCacheAttribute` to the filters on application start.

There's probably `RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);` in your `Application_Start`. So inside `RegisterGlobalFilters` add:

```
filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute { Duration = 300, VaryByHeader = "Host", VaryByParam = "myparam" });
```

Obviously this could have unintended side effects since nearly everything that is rendered will be cached for 300 seconds. If you don't want to have that on every single action, I'd look into the `[OutputCache]` attribute, and decorate the controllers you want to be cached.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for you answer, you almost nailed it, I just need to be able to filter some URL's and AFAIK if I use the GlobalFilters I won't be able to do it. The idea is to avoid using `[OutputCache]` on every Controller/Action.

Comment: @EdgarGriñant You could extend `OutputCacheAttribute` and add your own code to turn on and off dynamically depending on which URL/action/controller is requested.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to figure out how to do it extending `OutputCacheAttribute`. I guess I have to play with the `OnActionExecuting` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should try building a custom cache attribute.

In that custom attribute skip the cache, if the url (Request.Url.ToString()) contains the 'private' keyword.

For an easy sample on how to build a custom cache attribute, use this [blogpost](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/10/15/partial-output-caching-in-aspnet-mvc/) from Steven Sanderson. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @HCJ thanks for you answer, my custom `ActionFilterAttribute` that I describe in my question is mainly based on that code. And AFAIK this code is not thread safe and do not respect content types, it's a good essay, but it's not ready for a production environment. The changes I made over this code is applying URL filtering as you described, support for varbyparam and varybyheader, and also instead of generating the key based on routes and parameters I did it using URL, but I still need it thread safe and respect the content type.

Comment: Looking at the comments on the blogpost I have seen someone saying that he could solve the content-type issue: http://blog.rthand.com/post/2009/03/21/Partial-Output-Caching-in-ASPNET-MVC-updated.aspx I will try it